# Best algorithm for find similar text

Tags: php, algorithm, similarity

I'm trying to unify the records in a database, I'm using the levenshtein algorithm and works for some cases,

Working sample (distance <= 2):

```
* --------- * ---------- * -------- *
|  Looking  |    Finds   | Distance |
* --------- * ---------- * -------- *
| No existe | No Existe  |     1    |
| desempleo | Desempleo  |     1    |    
* --------- * ---------- * -------- *
```

thats great but ignores cases with mayor distances like:

- `Femenino` and `FEMENINO` with 7 distance

**Note**: I'm looking for a PHP solution

Comment: compare lower cased strings

Comment: Call `strtolower()` on both strings before comparing them.

Comment: are you using the `levenshtein()` PHP function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare

```
   echo levenshtein("Femenino", "FEMENINO");    // 7
```

VS

```
 echo levenshtein(strtolower("Femenino"), strtolower("FEMENINO"));  //0
```

If alphabet case doesn't matter for your application, make both the strings same case before you compare and you'll get significant improvement.